# can not find element using watir webdriver

Tags: ruby, testing, cucumber, watir

I am trying to click on the button.

```
<input data-ember-action="797" value="Search Now" class="cta-1st clrboth primary search-button firepath-matching-node" type="button">
```

but it keep showing an error of not finding the element to click. 
it finds all the elements until the end but when it comes to "click" it throws an error. My code is like this:

```
 @browser.div(:id=>'ember730').section(:class=>'tab-pane fade active in').form(:class=>'flight-search ').input(:class=>'cta-1st clrboth primary search-button').click
```

Am I missing something?
I am using Watir

Comment: There are a number places that this could be failing. It would help if you can share a page that reproduces the exception, as well as the exact exception.

Comment: As a random guess, I would try simplifying the approach. Are there really that many search buttons that require being so specific on where to find the button? Do all of those CSS classes actually help be more specific? I'd start off with `@browser.button(class: 'search-button').click` and then only add more specifics if needed.

Comment: There are 5 buttons which are in the different section have the same class name "search-button".

Comment: Also, which Watir version? Locating multiple classes with the `:class` key has been deprecated. With the latest version (6.7.1 was released today), you would want to put the ones you care about into an array `['cta-1st', 'clrboth', 'primary', 'search-button']`. Also prefer the `#button` method over the generic `#input` method

Comment: @user1669556 can you show what put `@browser.button(class: 'search-button').length` returns? I would be willing to bet it is returning an array and you need to put `@browser.button(class: 'search-button').first.click`

Comment: a larger sample of the page HTML might help, or if you could provide a link to the page in question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for all the help here. the problem was, I had a wrong reading in one of the elements.
I was missing this part.

```
@browser.div(:id=>'ember730').section(:class=>'tab-pane fade active in').form(:class=>'flight-search ').text_field(:class=>'cta-1st clrboth primary search-button firepath-matching-node').click
```

Answer (score 0):

As there is `value="Search Now"` section of `type="button"` here, following simple code snippet should do. I have made this working using Watir in my project..

```
@browser.button(value: "Search Now").click
```